# Noun form of primary

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that would equate to primariness, but which isn't so clumsy. Something like 'primarity', though it doesn't exist.

> "Thing has the quality of …"

Comment: Are you thinking of *primality*? That's probably not quite what you want, though.

Comment: Not primal, primary

Comment: Please explain the downvote, because if the reason is that you couldn't think of an answer, it's not a good way to say it.

Comment: @Anon If you want others to explain downvotes (& it wasn't mine!), please don't be Anonymous yourself.

Comment: Anon, at times a down vote means "I don't know the answer, and that's *your* fault." ;)

Comment: @TrevorD How are those even related?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is ***primacy***

- the fact of being pre-eminent or most important [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/primacy)
- The state of being first or foremost [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/primacy)
- the state of being first (as in importance, order, or rank) [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/primacy)

Comment: -1 Where is the noun?

Comment: The noun is _primacy_, like I said. It's defined, in each of those three links, as a noun. Is there something I missed?